# When i start sudo apt update this appears ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade, configure

```
Hit:1 (https://)dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 (https://)dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                  
Hit:3 (https://)archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                          
Hit:4 (https://)ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease   
Hit:5 (https://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease         
Hit:6 (https://)archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Hit:7 (https://)archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Hit:8 (https://)archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

i got this when i start "sudo apt update" ,how to fix this?
note: i change https:// with (https://) because i cant put the link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i just want to get rid of this notifications `W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository '(http://)archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)`

Comment: it's already worked so, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Debian or Ubuntu repositories, you can usually use a web browser to view the contents of the repository directories.

For example, if the repository URL is `https://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu`, add `/dists` to the end and browse to https://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists. Right now, [the https version of
archive.canonical.com seems to be down](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/archive.canonical.com?proto=https), so [look at the http version](http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists) instead.

You'll be able to browse into the `hirsute` directory and verify for yourself that there are no `universe` nor `multiverse` sub-directories in it, only `partner` (and `by-hash`, which is part of the repository infrastructure and not important here).

On the other hand, [the HTTP version of archive.**ubuntu**.com](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/) has the `universe` and `multiverse` repositories.

So you would need to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and/or any `*.list` or `*.sources` files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory, to change any lines mentioning the `universe` or `multiverse` repositories and the URL `https://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu` to use the URL `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` instead.

Comment: thanks man, its worked!